# Unable to use Share extension in macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applications, sharing

Update：I found that everything goes fine when I works in another User account of the computer.

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 on a 2015 Retina MacBook Pro 13" (2015).

Whenever I use the Share extension from any app, I get share screen alright, but after selecting the appropriate sharing provider, the appeared Share sheet(the second image below) become stuck and nothing can be done. I have to quit the invoking app to make the Share sheet disappear. This behaviour is observed even with Finder.app when attempting to share via AirDrop.

What could be the possible reason for the issue? I have tried erasing the disk and recovering it from my Time Machine backup, but to no avail. How do I resolve the issue?

Please refer to the images below:

[image: Sharing a note from Bear to Notes]

[image: The the share screen in the middle is stuck]

Comment: I am not sure what could be causing this issue. I would start by removing all Internet and iCloud accounts from System Preferences and logging back in again.

Comment: could you explain what makes you think Internet and iCloud accounts might be points? I mean these works might in fact have nothing to do with networks when you use share extension only between local apps.